# How to split a multiselect picklist into a String array and check if it contains a specific value within an iteration?

Tags: apex, string, multi-select, boolean

I have an iteration of DelegatedAccount (Standard SF object). When Im using obj.picklistValues.split(';').contains(value) its returning false. This is surprising as its a simple operation and should return true.

Here is the code

Class 1:

```
List<String> alignmentsMyAccountTab = new List<String>{'Account Owner','External','Manual'};

for (DelegatedAccount delAcc: emaAccountList ){
    if(delAcc.ECX_Alignment_Type__c == ECX_GlobalConstants.PRIMARY_ALIGNMENT){  // this works

         System.debug('split roles are'+ (delAcc.ECX_Roles__c).split(';'));  //1
         System.debug('dhdh'+(delAcc.ECX_Roles__c).split(';')[1]);          //2
         System.debug('bool valuex after match'+                           //3
         ((delAcc.ECX_Roles__c).split(';')).contains(ECX_GlobalConstants.NON_INHERITED_ROLE));

// System.debug('bool valuey after match'+ (delAcc.ECX_Alignment_Type__c    //commented 4 
 == ECX_GlobalConstants.PRIMARY_ALIGNMENT) && delAcc.ECX_Roles__c != null
                 && (delAcc.ECX_Roles__c).split(';').contains(ECX_GlobalConstants.NON_INHERITED_ROLE));
    }

    // below if condition not working
    if(alignmentsMyAccountTab.contains(delAcc.ECX_Alignment_Type__c) || (delAcc.ECX_Alignment_Type__c == ECX_GlobalConstants.PRIMARY_ALIGNMENT &&
((delAcc.ECX_Roles__c) != null && (delAcc.ECX_Roles__c).split(';').contains(ECX_GlobalConstants.NON_INHERITED_ROLE)))){
```

Class 2: (ECX_GlobalConstants)

```
public static final String INHERITED_ROLE = 'Inherited';
public static final String NON_INHERITED_ROLE = 'Non-Inherited';
public static final String PRIMARY_ALIGNMENT = 'Primary';
```

my `delAcc.ECX_Roles__c` contains the following in database - `Inherited;Non-Inherited`. The ECX_roles__c is a MultiPicklist

For the above code this is what I see in console

[image]

Also surprisingly if I uncomment the 4th System.debug in my code - deployment fails with message

> Only Boolean Values can be applied with logical operators.

I thought `String.split(';').contains(StringValue)`  will return a boolean. My if condition is also failing.

I am confused and unable to understand this behaviour

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the declarations (if not the exact values) of your various constants. Typing issues may relate to the types for these values.

Comment: edited the question to include the constants

Comment: Check precedence in your commented out line 4. Use brackets if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constant is `Non-Inherited` (uppercase `I`), while the value in the multipicklist is `Non-inherited` (lowercase `i`), they are not the same string.
Only the [equality operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) (`==`) and WHERE clause in SOQL run a case-insensitive check against Strings.

Just chaging your constant to `Non-inherited` should solve the issue.
In similar cases you could also build a Set of lowercase (or uppercase) strings, then checking if it contains your lowercase (or uppercase) string, i.e.:

```
Set<String> lowercaseRoles = new Set<String>();
for (String ecxRole : delAcc.ECX_Roles__c.split(';')) {
    lowercaseRoles.add(excRole.toLowerCase());
}
if (lowercaseRoles.contains(ECX_GlobalConstants.NON_INHERITED_ROLE.toLowerCase()) {
    // something
}
```